# How to improve accuracy of my ANN regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and python. I made a small ANN regression model to predict values which actually range from 1 to 10.
The data I am using has 799 input features and 1 output feature. Please suggest some ways to improve accuracy.
My predicted values are  (+-) 2.56 of the actual value.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features, h1, h2,  out_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, h1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)
        
        self.out = nn.Linear(h2,out_features)
        

    def forward(self,x):
        
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
       
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
       
        x = self.out(x)
       

        return x



# Train the Model
import time
start_time = time.time()

torch.manual_seed(32)
epochs = 100
losses = []

model = Model(in_features, h1= 900, h2= 900, out_features = 1)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =0.0001)

for i in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear the gradients from the previous iteration
    # print(conts_total)
    output = model(train_model_input_normalized)  # Forward pass
    loss = criterion(output, train_y_out_normalized)  # Calculate the loss
    losses.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()  # Backward pass
    optimizer.step()  # Update the weights

    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {i}, Loss {loss.item():.4f}")

# print(f"Epoch {i}, Loss {loss.item():.4f}")  # print the last line
print(f"\nDuration {time.time() - start_time:.0f} seconds") # print the time elapsed


# Validate the Model
# To Evaluate the Entire Test Set

with torch.no_grad():
  output = model(test_model_input_normalized)  # Forward pass
  test_outputs = output * ( y_out.max() -  y_out.min()) +  y_out.min()
  test_targets = test_y_out_normalized *( y_out.max() -  y_out.min()) +  y_out.min()
  
  # loss = criterion(output, test_y_out_normalized)  # Calculate the loss
  loss = criterion(test_outputs,test_targets)
  rmse_loss = torch.sqrt(loss)

print(f'RMSE:{rmse_loss:.8f}')
```

Please suggest some ways to improve accuracy?

**Edit**

The shape of the input training and testing data is:

```
Training set shape: torch.Size([14317, 799])
Training set shape: torch.Size([6136, 799])
```

The shape of the output training and testing data is:

```
torch.Size([14317, 1])
torch.Size([6136, 1])
```

Comment: Very hard to give any kind of useful advice here without knowing how many data points you have or what kind of problem it is.

Comment: Thank you @NickODell for the response. I have edited the question to include the shape of input and output data. I am seeing some libraries like XGBRegressor and CATBOOST.  Are these libraries useful?